# Compose Functions in Scala typeclass

Tags: scala

I have the following simple scala typeclass:

```
sealed trait Printable[A]{
  def format(v: A): String
}

object PrintDefaults{
  implicit val IntPrintable = new Printable[Int] {def format(v: Int): String = v.toString}
  implicit val StringPrintable = new Printable[String] {def format(v: String) = v.toString}
}


object Print {
 def format[A: Printable](v: A): String = implicitly[Printable[A]].format(v)
 def print[A: Printable](v: A): Unit = println(format(v))
 def print2[A: Printable](v: A): Unit = format(v) andThen println  
}
import PrintDefaults._
Print.format(3) // returns "3"
Print.print(3) // prints 3 
Print.print2(3) // does nothing
```

Why is Print.print2 not printing ? I would like to "compose" a method called print that allows me to not have to call println(format(v)) but rather chain println after calling format(v)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works.

`f andThen g` returns a function, it does not call the function. Calling the function would be `(f andThen g)(x)` which would return (or have the effect of) `g(f(x))`.

`print2` compiles because `String` can be converted to `StringWrapper` (`implicit wrapString in Predef`), `StringWrapper` is a `Seq[char]`, and a `Seq[Char]` is a (Partial) `Function[int, Char]`.

Just because of that, `format(v) and then println` compiles, as format(v) happens to be a function, and its return type, `Char` is compatible with `println` (which accepts `Any`).

`print2` result type would be `Function[Int, Unit]`, but you can type any method with return type Unit, it just causes the result to be discarded. Anyway, it has no side effect, and will not print.

You would probably get close to what you intended with something like

```
val print2 = format andThen println
```